# How do I change CSS in Magento 2?

Tags: frontend, magento2

The website has a blog and I want to make a font a bit larger. How do I find the right CSS to change?

I used to do it in WordPress. You would just go inspect element, find .body and change font-size to 16px or whatever you want.

In Magento2 everything is in line 2.

Answer: You need to install gulp. After you install gulp you have to find where he stores his CSS. After that you need to run gulp so he can process it and viola.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is :

> You should not edit/modify files within pub/* or vendor/* directory.
> Pub is for deployment and vendor is for default structure, which you
> override via your template or custom modules. Instead:
>
> - create a new theme inside app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{yourTheme}/. You can use Blank or Luma
>   theme. You can also create new theme which inherites from Blank
>   (inheritance is defined within theme.xml). If you are already using
>   some theme then skip this step.
> - edit .less within your theme so the changes stay visible and don't get replaced when clearing the cache or upgrading the system.
> - Use grunt to compile your .less into deployment files.
> - You can also setup sourcemaps to pin point your styling within the theme .less files so you can be more productive.

See here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/96480

Personally i would advise you not to modify an installed theme, because after an update you will probably need to do it again.
If you know some CSS it should not be hard to make it in another theme.

Does it help ?

Comment: The theme is custom made. I literally have to change from font-size 14px to 16px. That's it. Is creating new theme really necessarily ? Feels like a bit of an overkill.

Comment: So you already made your theme ? What do you mean by custom-made ?

Comment: Company I work for made a theme. My task is to change blog posts from 14px to 16px but I can't find where to change it. If I inspect element, I don't get the location of the css, I get it's in the row 2 of some processed file. I don't do much frontend, let alone Magento2 frontend.

Comment: Ah, I see, then try to find the selector for this element (something like `.blog-post.content` ) . Once you found it,  you can search in your file for it. and modify it there. Another option would be to search for `font-size: 14px;`. But you may have a lot of it.

Comment: I found it but I don't really know how to change it. I'm guessing its using some kind of processor.

Comment: What's the file extension ? what's the class or the css looking like ? can you put it here or in your original query ?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: You need to install gulp. After you install gulp you have to find where he stores his css. After that you need to run gulp so he can process it and viola.

Comment: Who is "he"? Your answer could use more detail.